# SELECT tag values not getting in Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I have form field in my JSP page. It has Select tag with few values. I need to select only one value and based on that in my servlet I will forward to other pages.
Here is my JSP code for Select tag

```
<select name="options">
    <option>Choose Your Option</option>
    <option value="option1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="option2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="option4">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

In my servlet I am processing based on the selected value. Here is my servlet code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
String options[]=request.getParameterValues("options");
        if(options[0].equals("option1"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option1.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(options[0].equals("option2"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option2.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(options[0].equals("option3"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option3.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(options[0].equals("option4"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option4.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

And the real problem is, when I select Option 1 or Option 2 It will be forwarding to the respective pages. But if I select Option 3 or Option 4, It won't work. What is the problem? What should I do? Thanks

Comment: er, you know, you could have simply used `String option = request.getParameter("options")`. Also, what do you mean by _doesn't work_? Does it give you an error? If so, what does the error say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
String option = request.getParameter("options")
```

This will give the selected value

```
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
       String selectedValue=request.getParameterValues("options");
        if(selectedValue.equals("option1"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option1.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(selectedValue.equals("option2"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option2.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(selectedValue.equals("option3"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option3.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(selectedValue.equals("option4"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option4.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```

Comment: shouldn't it be request.getParameter("options") in the code instead of String selectedValue=request.getParameterValues("options"); ?

Answer (score 0):

you can only select one option ,so the true anser is :

```
String selectedValue=req.getParameter("genre");
if(option.equals("option1"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option1.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(option.equals("option2"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option2.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(option.equals("option3"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option3.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
        else if(option.equals("option4"))
        {
            RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("Option4.jsp");
            rd.forward(request, response);
        }
    }
```